# uploading image file outside of webroot and accessing them via Html helper

Tags: php, cakephp

I have my application in **/var/www/html/Myapp/** .So webroot will be
 **/var/www/html/Myapp/app/webroot/..** .But I want to upload files on **/var/www/html/uploads/** directory and get images by Html helper 
**$this->Html->image()** from uploads directory not from by default **/img** directory of webroot.
So basically i don't want to use webroot of cakephp.If want to upload and get files outside of webroot directory.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: technically speaking, php ALWAYS uploads outside the webroot, and puts uploads into `/tmp/random_name`. it's user code that has to take that file and move it somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cakephp 2.x I don't think it's possible because the image method of HtmlHelper uses the function assetUrl, which in turn only takes resources from the assets directory. You could write or use a plugin to handle the upload file and put it in other directory, however it must still be within your webroot. Also you could use relative paths with the ROOT definition from  the outermost index.php

More info about HtmlHelper source code [here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-HtmlHelper.html#790-837)

Comment: uploading its not a problem but fetching them by a helper is needed .Need a custom helper or plugin which can fetch images/files from anywhere of server( must be outside of webroot)

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded files will need to be in a web accessible directory to be viewable in the browser. If you don't want to store your files in Cake's `webroot` you can use a symbolic link so that the directory containing the uploads can be accessed.

On your server create a symbolic link in the webroot to your uploads directory:-

```
ln -s /var/www/html/uploads/ /var/www/html/Myapp/app/webroot/uploads
```

Then you can access your uploaded images like:-

```
echo $this->Html->image('../uploads/example.gif');
```

Comment: i don't want to use symbolic links anymore. Seeking for an approach to get files from anywhere of server by default html helper

Comment: If you don't use symbolic links then your files won't be accessible from the webroot and therefore the HTML helper won't be able to serve them. Are you trying to protect files behind some form of authentication? Perhaps this is of help: http://andy-carter.com/blog/downloading-files-as-request-responses-in-cakephp-23.